# Gather config file variable names - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a config file (./leaderboard.json) that looks as follows:

```
{"usercount<@22>":1,"usercount<@386679122614681600>":2}
```

In my index.js file I'm trying to console.log all the names of the variables in the leaderboard.json file.

So the output would essentially be: usercount<@22>, usercount<@386679122614681600>

Is there anyway to currently do so? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded json file into `config` variable.
To extract keys, use `Object.keys(config)`

Answer (score 0):

First read the JSON file and `JSON.parse()` the data.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('jsonfile', 'utf8'));
```

Use `Object.keys()` to get all the usernames from the data.

```js
   var obj={"usercount<@22>":1,"usercount<@386679122614681600>":2}
console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```